# Getting mails in draft folder on Outlook WA to behave like drafts

Tags: outlook-web-access

I work for an organisation that has decided on the following asymmetric configuration of Exchange:

- internal users can read email via IMAPS and send email via SMTP
- external users can read email via IMAPS and can't send email

This is great when I'm on the inside, I can use `mutt`.  Not so great on the outside, I have to use Outlook Web Access (OWA).

At times I really can't stand OWA, especially since the admins have set the timeout so low that I regularly am logged out in the middle of writing an email.  What I'd really like is to read emails in `mutt`, write replies, but not send them, instead just save them to the drafts folder.  When I'm all done I can log in to OWA and just rapidly send off all the emails in the drafts folder.  Except of course that OWA doesn't allow that.  For some reason the mails I save to the drafts folder from `mutt` aren't recognised as drafts in OWA.  Because of this I can only read my drafts in OWA, not edit them or send them off :(

So, my question is, is there some magical incantation that makes OWA recognise an email as a draft (placing it in the drafts folder obviously isn't it)?  Maybe there's some undocumented header or something...

Comment: "Drafts" folders are usually device-centric when it comes to IMAP.  The emails don't leave the local Drafts folder until it's sent (or moved to a folder that's stored on-line).  Also, if OWA is timing out after you're idle for a bit, ensure you pick "This is a private computer" before you log in -- it keeps it from doing that (unless the IT staff have forced it)

Comment: It sure leaves the local device, since I do see it in OWA after editing it in `mutt` and saving the message in the drafts folder.  So that isn't the problem at all.  The problem is that the messages saved in the drafts folder aren't editable as drafts!  It's not only the timeout that irritates me, the OWA editor is vastly inferior to `vim` and the quoting of replies in Outlook sucks too ;)

Comment: There is a possibility to edit a message in Outlook: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/997deec1-0e79-43d2-924f-52404031c505/editchange-subject-in-owa-2010 unfortunately it doesn't work in OWA :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bit of an ugly way to do what I want.  The combination of an arguably broken reply marker in OWA (it only puts in a reply header rather than modify each line, e.g. adding a '>') and *Reply All* offers an acceptable solution.  I just have to remember removing the reply header inserted at the top of the mail.